# Take only Days from Interval Column - Postgresqk

Tags: sql

I am trying to take **only the days value** from the below interval type column.

To do so, I ran the following query but all it did was round everything to days as shown in the table below:

```
select date_trunc('days', avg(d.date)) as Days_till_invite
from datamodel d

0 years 0 mons 173 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 173 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 173 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 173 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 173 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 172 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 172 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 172 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 172 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 172 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 171 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 171 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 171 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 170 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
0 years 0 mons 170 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
```

**Desired Output**

Ideally, the output should just be: (only extracting the day value)

```
173
173
173
173
172 
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way uses `epoch`:

```
select extract(epoch from d.date) / (24 * 60 * 60) as days
```